# WPF C# - Headers behaviors

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

How can I reproduce the effect of scrolling through the headers like in [this](http://codepen.io/chrissp26/full/gBrdo) example?

I would like a nice sticky header that pushes the current one up in place of the new one. I found a great tutorial on how to do this natively for Android, but I'm looking to do it with WPF (XAML) and C#.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Don't think there is anything that is native to WPF that does this for you, there may be something in windows 8 that has this. I terms of answering your question if you want it in WPF then you will need to write your own custom control. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but it looks like you might be looking for the WPF Expander *OR* a comparable DataGrid grouping template.  Have you checked those?

Comment: Making the different groups is not an issue at all but it is the scrolling effect i would liek to replicate but proving hard to do.